# When to use reduce-kv over reduce in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

What is the difference between **reduce** and **reduce-kv**?

When to use *reduce-kv* over *reduce* or vice versa?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Whenever you're reducing associative collections, you should see a performance improvement when using `reduce-kv` due to it not allocating vectors/tuples for the key/value pairs. `reduce` will work on collections (and maps treated as collections of key/value tuples), but `reduce-kv` will only work on associative structures like maps and vectors.

From the `IKVReduce` protocol docstring:

> "Protocol for concrete associative types that can reduce themselves
>      via a function of key and val faster than first/next recursion over map
>      entries. Called by clojure.core/reduce-kv, and has same
>      semantics (just different arg order)."

The difference in *using* them is that you don't need to destructure the key/value in your reducing function:

```
(reduce (fn [m [k v]]
          (assoc m k (str v)))
        {}
        {:foo 1})

(reduce-kv (fn [m k v]
             (assoc m k (str v)))
           {}
           {:foo 1})
```